# Stuck in a boot loop with no explanation why

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, stock-android, boot, boot-loop

- Device: 2012 ZTE Score
- Android version : Stock 2.3.4 Gingerbread
- Status : Never rooted

---

I was right about to charge it when the battery died and the OS shut down the power. I reconnect it to charge while it's off, and unplugged after about 30 minutes. It starts up and works fine, but stays in a loop between the MetroPCS bitmap shown before loading the lock screen and the ZTE animation binary that comes after the initial Android logo. I left it sitting and it did those 50 times in a row.

I have tried clearing the Cache in **Safe Mode** and rebooting but nothing helped.

**Note**: I do not want to Factory Restore it because nothing is backed up and there are important files in the Internal Storage which cannot be accessed externally (at least from what I know).

**Can anyone explain why this is happening?**

All **boot loop** issues I find online are occurring and circulated around the notion that this only happens when files conflict, usually associated with custom ROMs and such but I have never done any of that or altered anything, as well as any program I'm aware of.

It has done this boot loop error before but it would always eventually get out of it, but this time it's been doing it non-stop all day no matter what I've tried. What could I do?

Comment: Install a custom recovery (CWM, TWRP, etc) and make a backup of your phone. Then give it a factory reset and restore your backup. Hope it helps

Comment: @SuperThomasLab Thanks for the advice but OP mentioned it `Status : Never rooted` already. OP  also didn't mention any will to tweak any factory installed  data including Stock Recovery here. Not to mention doing such may void the device's warranty.

Answer (score 0):

Seems Like your Lock/Power Off button might have been stuck. Get it checked or keep constantly pressing it during boot up. Might just help.

Comment: But that's a comment. OP asked for explanation. Even we assume your suggestion might work out, it still doesn't explain or do reason with the question. Please elaborate more.